Reemplazar solo una parte de los registros de una columna de un dataframe
Tengo esta columna en un dataframe:
Columna:
1-PALABRA-A50
14-PALABRA-A50
1-PALABRA-A50
1-OTRO-A66
1-OTRO-A66
...
25-PALABRA-A50

p = 'WORD'
Lo que estoy intentando:
df['Columna']= np.where(df['Columna'].str.contains('PALABRA', na=False), p, df['Columna'] )

Lo que quiero es que me reemplace solo la palabra "PALABRA", no todo el contenido de esa fila.
Pero me reemplaza todo:
Columna:
WORD
WORD
WORD
1-OTRO-A66
1-OTRO-A66
...
WORD

Output deseado:
Columna:
1-WORD-A50
14-WORD-A50
1-WORD-A50
1-OTRO-A66
1-OTRO-A66
...
25-WORD-A50

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Usa pandas.Series.str.replace() directamente:
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Columna": (
        "1-PALABRA-A50",
        "14-PALABRA-A50",
        "1-PALABRA-A50",
        "1-OTRO-A66",
        "1-OTRO-A66",
        "25-PALABRA-A50")}
)
p = 'WORD'

df['Columna'] = df['Columna'].str.replace('PALABRA', p)


>>> df
    
       Columna
0   1-WORD-A50
1  14-WORD-A50
2   1-WORD-A50
3   1-OTRO-A66
4   1-OTRO-A66
5  25-WORD-A50


Al menos para el ejemplo de datos que muestras no necesitas complicarte usando NumPy. En este caso es simplemente aplicar str.replace() de las cadenas de Python de forma vectorizada.
También se puede usar pandas.Series.replace() que es más general (no solo se aplica a cadenas), aunque str.replace() es preferible para substituciones de subcadenas en una única columna/serie. Quizás, una ventaja de pandas.Series.replace() es que permite realizar múltiples substituciones diferentes en una sola llamada, usando un diccionario por ejemplo:
>>> df['Columna'] = df['Columna'].replace(
...     {'PALABRA': "WORD", "OTRO": "OTHER"},
...     regex=True
... )

>>> df
       Columna
0   1-WORD-A50
1  14-WORD-A50
2   1-WORD-A50
3  1-OTHER-A66
4  1-OTHER-A66
5  25-WORD-A50

